Underline the selected navitem after open link in new tab
I have a navbar that the selected/active navitem is recognizable by an orange underline. However, when I open another navitem in a new tab (by rightclick), the default navitem is underlined and not the selected one!
Here is my navbar:
<div>
  <ul>
    <a routerLink="/home">
      <button class="active" data-bs-toggle="tab">
        Home
      </button>
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/newTab">
      <button data-bs-toggle="tab">
        New Tab
      </button>
    </a>
  </ul>
<div>

and .scss:
.active {
    border-bottom-color: #f48024!important;    
}


I understand the home tab has active class by default, but is there anyway to catch which tab was selected in the previous tab?
Thank you in advance.

You should use routerLinkActive attribute which take in an input of the class name and automatically adds the class to the active route.
<div>
  <ul>
    <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
      <button data-bs-toggle="tab">
        Home
      </button>
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/newTab" routerLinkActive="active">
      <button data-bs-toggle="tab">
        New Tab
      </button>
    </a>
  </ul>
<div>

Then you can update the CSS to:
.active > button {
    border-bottom-color: #f48024!important;    
}


Yes it seems a cleaner practice.

Don't use
class="active"

Instead bind it to a variable which is read during initialization.
You can read path using
window.location.href


Yes it worked! Thank you.
